# Outlook Javascript API - open external web page

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-api

Quick question about the new Outlook Javascript based API - I wan't to open an external web page, obviously `window.open` does the job very well.

It works on Outlook Web, but on desktop, it looks like the browser opened is tied to the appointment in which the add-in is displayed - when I close the window in Outlook, the browser get closed as well. Any tips how I could avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook Addin provides API  called [getDisplayDialogAsync()](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.ui.html#displayDialogAsync)

The browser window opened from Outlook is tied to the appointment / mail . It is expected that the window will be closed as user switches out of the mail or closes the appointment window. It is an expected behaviour.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of it. So there is no way to just integrate with a web app by opening it in a separate browser? I'm not a fan of this design decision as it makes the add-in not consistent between Web and Desktop